# How can we inject a attribute directive to the DOM element ( from ts file ) in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, dom-manipulation

Is it possible to add a directive to DOM element using setAttribute()?

I was trying to implement drag and drop in my component with material drag and drop.
it is working, when i tried like this

```
<div class="example-boundary">
<div class="example-box" #test cdkDragBoundary=".example-boundary" cdkDrag>
    I can only be dragged within the dotted container
</div>
```

from  my understanding, drag functionality work through ***cdkDrag*** attribute directive.

When i tried to add this directive through setAttribute(), which is not working

```
constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2, private _elRef: ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   let requiredElem = this._elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.example-box');
   this._renderer.setAttribute(requiredElem[0], 'cdkDrag', '');
}
```

When i checking the DOM, seems cdkDrag is added.
[image]

have any one to help me to sort this out?
thanks in advance.

### Edit

I have implemeted that drag functionality in iframe element using jquery (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-syoi3w?file=src/app/iframe/iframe.component.ts) this slackBlitz example facing an issue with jqueryUi lib.

Comment: You can't do that in this way, because the `directive` should be within the `template` to be initialized by Angular. But why you don't use it directly by adding it to the template?

Comment: I have requirement like, implement drag & drop functionality inside an elements in the Iframe.
So I thought, choose the required dom elements from the iframe and add this directive.

Comment: iframe are completely different page (child dom) loaded by parent page and angular will not have control over it unless the iframe src is also an angular app, in which case it is a different instance.

Comment: @JpVinjamoori So we can't do this?
do you have any other suggestion to full fill this requirement?

I am already implemented this using jquery draggable().  I want to avoid the use of jquery

Comment: Check the `cdkDrag` [source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/0baca1878014a5b3c35d1bce2bbf3a170f88c1df/src/cdk/drag-drop/directives/drag.ts), to see if you can do any workaround or custom implementation using the same functionalities used there.

Comment: actually, implemented the requirement using jquery. I tried to create a slackBlitz link.. but facing an issue with jqueryUi. (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-syoi3w?file=src/app/iframe/iframe.component.ts) . may be some of you guys can help me to avoid that jquery dependency.

Comment: I don't know regarding the jQuery, but regarding the cdkDragDrop, I'm not sure if you can create an object of `CdkDrag` and pass it to the `CdkDropList.addItem` method, I think worth it to give it a try.

Comment: okay. i will try that

Comment: I am not sure why you use iframe. See if you can use Shadow DOM in its place. Shadow DOM can replace iframe for few scenarios. When you use shadow dom, you can use all your app's modules/directive. Check encapsulation: `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` at https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, you can't do this in Angular. What you're looking for was possible in the old angular.js, by using the `$compile` service. For eg:

```
element.setAttribute('cdkDrag', '');
$compile(element)($scope);
```

But, for a number of good reasons, the Angular team decided to drop support for such dynamic approaches in the new framework.

In the first few RC versions of Angular, there were some workarounds/hacks based on `DynamicComponentLoader` that would allow one to achieve a dynamic directive compilation on DOM elements, but later `DynamicComponentLoader` was also deprecated and then removed.